# How to extend type of Function return value Base TS generics

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a TS problem about using generics in Function.
In summary, I would like to write a function, which accepts a array of objects which has a specific interface. And in my function, I do something, and add a new property named 'children' on each item in array.
How can I write TS type on this function? When I use this function, I will know the return value has the same type of input array of object, and !! has children property also. I try to use generics, but not work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

below is my example code.

```
// src array
const src = [
  { id: 3, parentId: 2 },
  { id: 2, parentId: 1 },
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 4 },
  { id: 5, parentId: 4 },
  { id: 6, parentId: 8 },
  { id: 7, parentId: 9 },
  { id: 7, parentId: 9, title : 'ssss' },
];

interface Src {
  id:number;
  parentId? : number | string;
  title? : string
}
// I use generics, but return value cant has children on each items of array
function test<T extends Src>(arr : Array<T>) :Array<T> {
  for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    // add children here
    arr[i].children = {xxxxx}
  }
  return arr;
}
let a = test(src)
// I want ts can tell me, each items in res array, has the same type of src, but also be added children property
let res = test(src)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really use some array utility method like `map` to achieve this

```
function test<T extends Src>(arr : Array<T>) {
  return arr.slice().map(item => ({
    ...item,
    children: { xxx: "XXX" }
  }))
}
```

this will add `children: {xxx: "XXX}` to every element and return the modified array with the correct type.

```
let srcWithChildren = test(src)
src[0].children // <--- Error.Property doesn't exist.
srcWithChildren[0].children // <--- OK. Typescript knows about the new property.
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGcCcGNQQ0pOBPAUNA9gO3AFwjKALygDaqooA3qAJYAmAXKAMwA0oADggKZa4BJJqABMoAL5sK1OsJEdukPoOEBGCVMo0GzdZOnbhAFg0HZzAKwLe-IcxP6t50ADZrS28IAcppztAA7O7KdqAAnL4y-kFcNirMYRy4tLgANjygzADk4LngWaYAugDcqKi0-DyQAGZw0BkAyoRU0jpYAK4AtgBGVaWUiiH0APyZoB09VaAAPhC4kBUA5v2gyWk8o8x4C1iLqOJl1e1Y0MnYqzx4ADwAKqA8AB64fPTgoE3QAHwAFAiQYwBBRAoW6fACU1GkSlw7UgWHgiAAdOBUrR6t8wYjOnBON8UjxOsRPqBvi1KJREZT8Z1NOToAALWipegeZg0B4c5gAIgAGnyuRJpOIwWD9mUQKABKAAO5wfirN7QOUXVKpUCdHgcHh1el0Z6dN4VUBKN5-FAcelwN64ekZcBwDWrZCcDIYaoEaAcbrtfBwVLgDCgXrwej0Hj0UAMpksvhcSAYF2QXBodL4E3EC54b5QaCinOkAAMhURUeZHlAEquAFoa6AAArxxPJ0D0DCXLBZfCPWh4RGoE2F4ulmPwys1qugG7Oy7QBacfAAaywGGlpu6GB9q1t4x40rjCaqycRQA)

```js
const src = [
  { id: 3, parentId: 2 },
  { id: 2, parentId: 1 },
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 4 },
  { id: 5, parentId: 4 },
  { id: 6, parentId: 8 },
  { id: 7, parentId: 9 },
  { id: 7, parentId: 9, title : 'ssss' },
];

function test(arr) {
  return arr.slice().map(item => ({
    ...item,
    children: { xxx: "XXX" }
  }))
}

console.log(test(src))
```

Answer (score -1):

Aside of @soffyo's answer, to adjust the return type to also contain the new property "children", you'll want to create a new type.

This could be done inline

```
function test<T extends Src>(arr : Array<T>) :Array<T & { children: object }> {
    for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        // add children here
        arr[i].children = {xxxxx}
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Or via type aliasing

```
type SrcWithChildren = Src & { children: object };

function test<T extends Src>(arr : Array<T>) :Array<SrcWithChildren> {
    for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        // add children here
        arr[i].children = {xxxxx}
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: You should really check my answer again, because it does return the correct type with the new property. Just look at the playground link. Plus, your answer is not valid typescript code.